# Run Umbraco 7 without database

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I understand that Umbraco caches all database content in an XML file on the web server. Would it be possible to run an Umbraco instance with just that file, and no database?

The idea would be to do all editing on an instance with a database, but have UAT and Live as read only environments without a database. Deploying dev to UAT or Live would mean copying all updated files and the XML file to the database-less UAT or Live instances.

Comment: "I understand that Umbraco caches all database content in an XML file on the web server. " - This statement is incorrect, a content cache is stored in an XML file on disk but not all database content. There is still a reliance on some data stored in the database.

Comment: @ProNotion Ok, you're right. What I'm after is a solution where an Umbraco instance serves up a read only site without a database. So all info sits in files on the web server(s).

Comment: Unfortunately that is not yet a reality to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, please see [Decoupling Umbraco from your front-end website](http://www.wiliam.com.au/wiliam-blog/decoupling-umbraco-and-asp-net-mvc-5).